# When to recycle bitmap in android project?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, recycle

I have successfully implemented **lazy loading** of list images and list items in Android listview. I am using Android 4.0+ and Java 7.

The algorithm i followed is:

1. List data(including image URL) is downloaded from internet as and when user scrolls the list.
2. When scroll state is idle, list images are loaded.
3. In the background thread, images are first checked for in the cache. If not present in cache, they are downloaded and stored into the cache.
4. Lastly image is set to imageview in the listview and  adapter is notified.

The only problem is I am not clear about when to recycle bitmaps. I tried using bitmap.recyle() at many places but I got the following error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmap**

It is not possible to add that vast code over here. Also there are some privacy issues. Can someone please help me about this?

**EDIT**

My application size increases from 727 KB (at the time of installation) to 14 MB.
After I recycle my bitmaps, in getView() of adapter I get "**cannot generate texture from bitmap "**.
Can anyone suggest how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Recycling a bitmap renders it unusable. Only recycle when you're completely done with it. In your case, that means after it's been evicted from the cache. You'll also want to make sure that none of your existing views reference it.

Comment: Well that is the problem. I am reusing views in my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

As of ICS the need to recycle isn't necessary. There are a few instance where you would want to but considering most listview implementations it probably won't be necessary.

You can check out this video by Chet Hasse for more info on *reusing* bitmaps which would be better if they are the same size. [DevBytes: Bitmap Allocation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8)

Comment: Yeah I know that. But I can't trust upon listview doing that for me. My application may have upto 22,000 bitmaps at a time. So I need to recycle them on my part. Is there any way you can suggest?

Comment: The listview would not be doing that for you. Afaik, it would be controlled at a lower level. Garbage collection would take effect when necessary and be reallocated when displayed again. If you still want to implement it, it would be like @kabuko said after the bitmap will no longer be used which might require a bitmap manager and some manual resetting.

Comment: What kind of manual resetting? Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap recycling should be performed differently in different versions of Android. It is best to implement in a way that covers the majority of versions.

As others here said, recycle() renders your bitmap unusable, recycle() is meant to be used once you are finished with the bitmap and would like to induce a garbage collection. I think you should use it on your activity onPause()/onStop().

See here for more information:
[Managing Bitmap Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)